# How to Visual C++ redistributive files (.dll) to my application in Visual Studio 2013/2015

Tags: visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, libraries, redistributable

I have a win32 application.I generated this application in Windows 7 x64 machine, when i copy this application to different machine (win7 x64) it is giving error missing .dll files. I added and linked c++ re-distributive files to my project but same error. I have used poco library in this project in my release file I am getting all .dll files required to run application but with c++ redistributive files are not.
Can anyone tell me how to copy .dll files from visual studio to my release folder.

Comment: This is covered in detail on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zebw5zk9.aspx). Have you read that material first?

Comment: Thanks for your response. i gone through MSDN and made changes to build statically but when i run my .exe in target machine it throwing error for vcruntime.dll files.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a setup script and add vcrun2013 package to it.To hold problems of this kind  look at "dll registration" chapter.

Comment: you mean make .msi and run in target machine. if that the case i don't want to install any on target machine, I just want run my .exe file directly